# How to concatenate many RGB images into one image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a hundred equal sized RGB images numbered from 1 to 100. I want to create one image out of them. For example, if I give row=10 and column=10 then the output should be such that the first 10 images will form the first row and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a 10-by-10 cell array containing your images, and then to use [CELL2MAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html) to catenate them into a large image.

```
nRows = 10;
nCols = 10;
imgCell = cell(nRows,nCols);

for iImage = 1:nRows*nCols

%# construct image name - fix this like so it conforms to your naming scheme
%# also, add the path if necessary
imageName = sprintf('image%i.jpg',iImage);

%# add the image to imgCell
%# images will filled first into all rows of column one
%# then into all rows of column 2, etc
imgCell{iImage} = imread(imageName);

end

%# if you want the images to be arranged along rows instead of 
%# columns, you can transpose imgCell here
%# imgCell = imgCell';

%# catenate into big image
bigImage = cell2mat(imgCell);

%# show the result
imshow(bigImage)
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for answering. Your coding will create a big image where the images will be concatenated in one row or one column. What I wanted is that first 10 images should be concatenated in the first row of the big resultant image. Next 10 the second row and so on to complete the 10 rows. if the images are of size 400x400. The resultant image will be 4000x4000. not 400x40000. I am sorry if i was not clear earlier.

Comment: @Shan: My code should create an image of 4k by 4k if there are 100 images of 400 by 400, if you run all of it, i.e. initialize imgCell properly.